Running Powershell from VBA with Administrator privileges
I have not been able to successfully run my PowerShell script from VBA with administrator privileges.
I have examined the various answers in this forum and attempted to adapt with no success.
When I execute the VBA script below, there is a window that will open for less than one second and then close (and I don't know if it is a Powershell or a Command window) and the script does not run as evidenced by not doing its job, and finishing immediately (not waiting the ten seconds). Also, there is nothing written to StdOut or StdErr
If the script is run from an elevated command window, or an elevated Powershell window, it runs as designed.
The script is designed to temporarily disconnect the network adapter. It is simplified at this stage and only works on an adapter named Ethernet.
Powershell Script
Disable-NetAdapter -name Ethernet -confirm:$false
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
Enable-NetAdapter -name Ethernet -confirm:$false

Functioning elevated command window code:
C:\PowerShell Scripts>"disable network temporarily.ps1"

Non-Functioning VBA Code
'Needs reference to Windows Script Host Object Model
Option Explicit
Sub TempNetworkDisable()
    Dim wshShell As wshShell
    Dim wshShellExec    As Object
    Dim strCommand      As String
    Dim strOutput

    strCommand = "pwsh.exe -c Start-Process -Verb RunAs pwsh.exe \"" -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NoExit -f `\""C:\PowerShell Scripts\Disable Network Temporarily.ps1`\"""
    
    Set wshShell = New wshShell
    Set wshShellExec = wshShell.Exec(strCommand)
    strOutput = wshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll()
    Debug.Print "StdOut:", strOutput

    strOutput = wshShellExec.StdErr.ReadAll()
    Debug.Print "StdErr:", strOutput
End Sub


Windows 11 Pro

Version  10.0.22631 Build 22631


PSVersion 7.4.6
Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2409 Build 16.0.18025.20160) 64-bit
VBA 7.1.1143


Try to run the powershell shell instead of running a script then manually run the script to test if required privileges is available.

Theoretically, office apps can be restricted to run smth. with elevated rights to prevent virus attacks.

Depending on the application you create, you can use a Windows service to perform such tasks. The application can interact with the service using custom commands.

@rotabor the Disable-NetAdapter command requires elevated privileges.



The immediate problem with your approach is that you were missing an escaped closing ":[1]
' Note the \"" before the closing "
' To run the elevated pwsh.exe process *synchronously*, i.e. to wait
' for it to exit, add -Wait before -Verb RunAs
strCommand = "pwsh.exe -c Start-Process -Verb RunAs pwsh.exe \""-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NoExit -f `\""C:\PowerShell Scripts\Disable Network Temporarily.ps1`\""\"""


Note that if you run the resulting command line from a non-elevated process, you'll get an interactive UAC prompt to authorize creation of an elevated process (a process running with administrative privileges, as requested via Start-Process -Verb RunAs).

The only way to avoid UAC prompts is to either run in an elevated process to begin with or to disable (parts of) UAC altogether, which is strongly discouraged.
Otherwise, there's only a limited workaround: Assuming that you are an administrator in principle, you can set up a scheduled task with a preconfigured command to be run with elevation, which you can then invoke on demand from a non-elevated process of yours without triggering a UAC prompt.
See this answer for more information.



However, this presents a follow-up problem: you're reading the stdout and stderr streams of the outer, transitory pwsh.exe, which will be empty, given that the nested, elevated pwsh.exe process launches in a new window, which means that its output streams aren't connected to the outer process.

Note:

Neither your outer pwsh.exe call (the one that facilitates launching another pwsh.exe process with elevation) nor your *.ps1 script are designed to produce output, so perhaps you don't need to solve this problem - assuming that no errors occur; if you do want to capture any errors, however, the problem does need solving.


Your only option is to capture the elevated process' output streams in (temporary) files.

While Start-Process does offer -RedirectStandardOutput and -RedirectStandardError parameters that accept file paths, they can not be used in your case, because these parameters syntactically cannot be combined with an elevation request (-Verb RunAs), a restriction that is also reflected in the underlying .NET APIs (see this answer for details).

Thus, you'll need to capture output from inside the elevated process, by using redirections there, which necessitates switching from a -f (-File)-based to a -c (-Command)-based CLI call.

You'll then have to read the target files' content in your VBA code after the fact.




' Note the addition of -Wait to the Start-Process call, 
' the switch to -c in the nested call, 
' the use of & the call operator to invoke the script, the
' switch to '...' quoting around the script-file path,
' and the > and 2> redirections with sample output file names
' stdout.txt and stderr.txt
strCommand = "pwsh.exe -c Start-Process -Wait -Verb RunAs pwsh.exe \""-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NoExit -c & 'C:\PowerShell Scripts\Disable Network Temporarily.ps1' >stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt\"""

' ...

' After synchronous execution (due to -Wait), read the output files, stdout.txt and stderr.txt
' Without -Wait, you'd have to track the lifetime of the elevated
' process manually.


[1] While your original code therefore had a syntax error, the way pwsh.exe quietly ignored it is actually a bug in the latter, as of PowerShell 7.4.x; a simple repro: pwsh -nop -c "\"hi" (from outside PowerShell; from PowerShell or a POSIX shell, use pwsh -nop -c '"hi'); see GitHub issue #14284.
However, the failure is - abstractly - reflected in the process exit code, which is set to 1.

Thank you. Something so simple -- a missing \\ . It's working now (except for having to deal with the UAC dialog). Is there any way to avoid dealing with that?

Also, now that it is working, I don't need to capture any errors, but thank you for your insight into that part of the code.

Hmm. I see that the bug you mention regarding ignoring the syntax error has been around for four years now.

@RonRosenfeld, unfortunately, yes. I've also added information near the top of the answer about how to avoid UAC prompts, which is generally ill-advised for security reasons, however.

Thank you. I will figure out a way to run the relevant excel file with elevated privileges. That seems to avoid the prompt.

"Your only option is to capture the elevated process' output streams in (temporary) files." This is completely not so. You can send the PID of the outer process to the inner process, which proceeds to duplicate the handles from the outer process.

Interesting, @Joshua. How does passing a PID relate to duplicating stream handles? Or are you saying that the elevated process must then manually perform duplication of the handles via the parent process' PID? Can you provide a minimal example or point to one? Remember that the outer process is non-elevated and the inner one elevated, and at least at the level of .NET's built-in APIs there appears to be no solution; see this answer

@mklement0: I could, but it's mass P/Invoke and I'm too bad at powershell to do it.
